# exception in plugin material design icon

Tags: android

I downloaded and installed android material design icon generator, and now I am trying to create new->material design icon, but an error occurs. Do I need import any libraries?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getAllResourceDirectories()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.konifar.material_icon_generator.MaterialDesignIconGenerateDialog.initResDirectoryName(MaterialDesignIconGenerateDialog.java:318)
    at com.konifar.material_icon_generator.MaterialDesignIconGenerateDialog.<init>(MaterialDesignIconGenerateDialog.java:126)
    at com.konifar.material_icon_generator.MaterialDesignIconGenerateAction.actionPerformed(MaterialDesignIconGenerateAction.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:265)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:282)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:292)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:265)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:35)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:546)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:878)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:823)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:704)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:465)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

That is report about error. How can I fix it? My java version is 12.0.1 and android studio 3.6.1

Comment: Same problem since I updated to Android studio 3.6.1. I think it was working fine with Android Studio 3.5 and lower

Comment: getting the same error with new Android Studio version

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved by update BIOS version and reinstall system Windows and reinstall Android Studio. I think my 5 years old BIOS version were a problem

Comment: yeah i dont think that was the problem